# javaws no response only in my pc windows 7 and other same pc is ok

Tags: windows-7, java

I have any application which run with jnlp and I installed `jre 7u80` on my pc,  when open the jnlp file , it show splash screen and then no response, but the `javaws.exe` and `jp2launcher` process are exist in task manager .

I have tried to uninstall and install jre again and  clear the user cache , then also same problem.

If any one face the same problem, your help is very appreciated.